# Processing pgSQL query results in batches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've written the rake task to perform a postgreSQL query. The task returns an object of class Result.

Here's my task:

```
task export_products: :environment do
  results = execute "SELECT smth IN somewhere"
    if results.present?
      results
    else
      nil
    end
end

def execute sql
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute sql
end
```

My further plan is to split the output in batches and save these batches one by one into a .csv file. 
Here I get stuck. I cannot imagine how to call find_in_batches method of ActiveRecord::Batches module for PG::Result.

How should I proceed?

Edit: I have a legacy sql query to a legacy database

Comment: Any specific reason why are you not using queries on Model instead of explicitly writing sql queries?

Comment: @Aakash Gupta I have a legacy sql query to a legacy database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at how [`find_in_batches` is implemented](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb#L98), you'll see that the algorithm is essentially:

1. Force the query to be ordered by the primary key.
2. Add a `LIMIT` clause to the query to match the batch size.
3. Execute the modified query from **(2)** to get a batch.
4. Do whatever needs to be done with the batch.
5. If the batch is smaller than the batch size, then the unlimited query has been exhausted so we're done.
6. Get the maximum primary query value (`last_max`) from the batch you get in **(3)**.
7. Add `primary_key_column > last_max` to the query from **(2)**'s `WHERE` clause, run the query again, and go to step **(4)**.

Pretty straight forward and could be implemented with something like this:

```
def in_batches_of(batch_size)
  last_max = 0 # This should be safe for any normal integer primary key.
  query = %Q{
    select whatever
    from table
    where what_you_have_now
      and primary_key_column > %{last_max}
    order by primary_key_column
    limit #{batch_size}
  }

  results = execute(query % { last_max: last_max }).to_a
  while(results.any?)
    yield results
    break if(results.length < batch_size)
    last_max = results.last['primary_key_column']
    results = execute(query % { last_max: last_max }).to_a
  end
end

in_batches_of(1000) do |batch|
  # Do whatever needs to be done with the `batch` array here
end
```

Where, of course, `primary_key_column` and friends have been replaced with real values.

If you don't have a primary key in your query then you can use some other column that sorts nicely and is unique enough for your needs. You could also use an `OFFSET` clause instead of the primary key but that can get expensive with large result sets.